# Calculating rank of a single row against the rest of the table

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a user profile table, and a tips table. The tips table has a foreign key, linking the user ID to tip.receiver. I need to be able to rank users by tips received. As I understand it, MySQL doesn't have a RANK() function. When selecting multiple rows, you can make a fairly easy substitute, as shown [here](http://blog.ubiq.co/calculate-rank-in-mysql/):

```
SELECT    id,score,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      scores p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  score DESC;
```

However, I want to be able to display the rank when selecting just one row. For instance, when looking at the user's profile page. I thought about using a subquery for this, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  Firstly you can go down the subquery method as you have already identified which will be less than ideal performance-wise i.e.

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.score,
    d.rank
FROM (
    SELECT    
        p.id,
        p.score,
        @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM      scores p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY  p.score DESC
) d
WHERE d.id = 12345;
```

Alternatively you could add an additional column into the users table, and then do an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to cache the rank value and then just select the row from the users table that corresponds to the user you'd like.  An example of the INSERT query would be the following

```
INSERT INTO usersTable (
    id,
    cachedRank
)
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.rank
FROM (
    SELECT    
        p.id,
        p.score,
        @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM      scores p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY  p.score DESC
) d
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    cachedRank = VALUES(cachedRank);
```

This would be more efficient in the long run.  You could put this into a stored procedure and have it scheduled using MySQLs event scheduler, for example.  Additionally the query could be adjusted to INNER JOIN onto the user table in the outer select) just to ensure that it only ever updates records instead of inserting any new ones (in the case of a foreign key inconsistency)